# How I can swap 3 dimensions with each other in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a `a= torch.randn(28, 28, 8)` and I want to swap dimensions `(0, 1, 2)` to `(2, 0, 1)`.
I tried `b = a.transpose(2, 0, 1)` , but I received this error:

```
TypeError: transpose() received an invalid combination of arguments - got 
(int, int, int), but expected one of:
 * (name dim0, name dim1)
 * (int dim0, int dim1)
```

Is there any way that I can swap all at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Pytorch's `permute()` function to swap all at once,

```py
>>>a = torch.randn(28, 28, 8)
>>>b = a.permute(2, 0, 1)
>>>b.shape
torch.Size([8, 28, 28])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute):

```
b = a.permute(2, 0, 1)
```