# How can I swap axis in a torch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, permutation

I have a torch tensor of size `torch.Size([1, 128, 56, 128])`

1 is channel, 128 is the width, and height. 56 are the stacks of images.

How can I resize it to `torch.Size([1, 56, 128, 128])` ?

Comment: Do you want to switch the dimensions so that the image stack dimension becomes the 2nd dimension? Or do you want to reshape the tensor so that you have one channel, 56 width, 128 images, and 128 height?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can swap 3 dimensions with each other in Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104138/how-i-can-swap-3-dimensions-with-each-other-in-pytorch)

Comment: @Cecilia Thankyou so much, it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use `permute` or `transpose`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`swapaxes`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.swapaxes.html#torch.swapaxes) function:

```py
my_tensor.swapaxes(1,2)
```